# Migrate an on-prem AD DL Group to Pure Office 365 DLs

Tags: active-directory, azure, outlook, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

Can anyone advise if there is a way to migrate on-prem AD groups to pure Office 365.

In our environment we have a hybrid configuration which uses AD Sync to synchronize ad objects to Azure. So we have DL groups which exist in both places. What we want to be able to do is to sever the connection of the on-prem group from 365 and remove it from on-prem AD.

The reason for doing this is that we want to be able to achieve the ability of being able to delegate 365 users the ability to manage the groups. We want to avoid removing and recreating them because of the issues this causes for users with the groups cached in their suggested contacts.

Can anyone advise if this is possible and how it is done? I have searched online, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present there is not a way to convert an user or group synced from on-premises to a cloud only version. You would have to delete and recreate it.

There is a Uservoice item you can vote on [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36479119-allow-conversion-of-ad-synced-accounts-to-in-clou).

Comment: Thanks for this. Microsoft really need to add a feature that will do this, deleting and recreating makes things messy!

Comment: You can do it in a script - it's not too bad. Create the new O365 group, list the on-prem group members and add them to the O365 group via powershell

Comment: What about Exchange security groups?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, delete and recreate it in cloud directly is the supported way.
For example : Deleting an Office 365 mailbox in hybrid deployment
http://www.brisk-it.net/deleting-office-365-mailbox-hybrid-deployment/